# accumulate from elements of a set - drools

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I want to sum the weight of unique panelist having (at least) one active viewing. A viewing has a panelist, a panelist has a weight (int).

I obtain the *set* of Panelists having an active Viewing like this:

```
accumulate(
    Viewing(active==true,
        $p : panelist),
    collectSet($p))
```

EDIT: Note that I am using a set as a way of getting the set of unique panelists.

I want to sum the weight of every panelist in this set. 
My attempt (below) is returning

```
java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet cannot be cast to com...domain.Panelist
```

Basically, *`a set is not a panelist, duh`*.

How can I access elements of the set, ideally using idiomatic drools rather than a Java hack?

This is my attempt:

```
rule "targetLevelReach"
    when
        $actualReach : Number(intValue>10) from accumulate (
            Panelist($weight : weight) from 
                 accumulate(
                     Viewing(
                         active==true, 
                         $p : panelist),
                     collectSet($p)),
            sum($weight))
    then
        ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building further on laune's idea:

```
rule "targetLevelReach"
when
    $actualReach : Number(intValue>10) from
      accumulate ( $p : Panelist
                   and exists Viewing( active==true, panelist == $p),
                   sum($p.getWeight() )
then
    ...
end
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that there can be several active viewings for the same panelist, I want the weight to be counted only once per panelist with at least one active viewing. Is your code achieving this? Or is the accumulate triggered by all viewings? It looks like it may be the efficient way of doing what I need :)

Comment: Just tried it and as I expected it is faster than the solution using a set by several orders of magnitude! Many thanks Geoffrey!

Comment: The `exists` keyword make sure that each panelist weight is only counted once :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first rule, the inner accumulate collects a Set of objects that are accessible from a Viewing object using getPanelist. This (I suppose - because you couldn't be bothered to supply the info) returns a Panelist. But a Set of Panelist isn't a Panelist, which you have as a result of the accumulate:

```
Panelist(...) from accumulate ( Viewing(...$p:...), collectSet($p) )
```

Therefore, Set cannot be cast to ... Panelist.

The second version does have Set() as the result of the above accumulate.

As each Panelist has a weight, all you need to do is

```
rule "targetLevelReach"
when
    $actualReach : Number(intValue>10) from
      accumulate ( Viewing( active==true, $p : panelist),
                   sum($p.getWeight() )
then
    ...
end
```

**Edit**

Now that we know that we have to eliminate duplicates in the Set of Panelist, we know that we have to accumulate an intermediary Set:

```
rule "targetLevelReach"
when
    $pset: Set() from accumulate ( Viewing( active==true, $p : panelist),
                                   collectSet($p) )   
    $actualReach: Number(intValue>10) from 
      accumulate( Panelist( $weight : weight) from $pset,
                  sum( $weight ) )
then
    ...
end


rule "targetLevelReach"
when
    accumulate ( Viewing( active==true, $p : panelist),
                 $pset: collectSet($p) )   
    accumulate( Panelist( $weight : weight) from $pset,
                $actualReach: sum( $weight ),
                $actualReach > 10 )
then
    ...
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a reason why I use a set: I want to sum the weights of unique panelists - meaning I don't want to count a panelists twice, even if they have several active viewings. I use the set as a way of "uniquifying" the panelists.

Comment: IMO explaining that "getViewing" returns a Viewing, getPanelists returns a Panelist and getXXX returns XXX... is pure clutter. I can share more info on my classes if needed, but the answer to my question seems quite unrelated to my particular classes. I tried to keep the noise to a minimum.

Comment: BTW, my end goal is to sum the weights of unique panelists, but I am absolutely not bent on using a Set if you see a better solution!

Comment: Essential information is never "noise". Not knowing what the type of some item is causes unnecessary headache. That duplicate Panelists need to be eliminated is something s.o. not acquainted with the problem domain cannot possibly know.

Comment: Did you mean to have `from $pset` in the second accumulate? I am still unsure of why chaining the accumulate does not work though! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You say "But a Set of Panelist isn't a Panelist, which you have as a result of the accumulate" But $pset is a set and not a panelist, so why would `from $pset`work any better? Yet it does! Looks more like a bug than a feature to my untrained eye...   Your answer does not address this and i am still puzzled!

Comment: Actually I had a mistake in there. `from $pset` was missing! I added a second version using the alternative syntax for `accumulate`. A Panelist is a single, simple object, and a Set is a collection. You can "from" both, but a single object will give you only a single object and `from $pset` iterates a collection. And if you have the accumulate produce a Set, the pattern preceding `from` must be of class `Set`.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, it is working when I do not chain the `accumulate` but use an intermediate variable instead. Keen to have an explanation though.

This is a working way of accumulating from the set:

```
$viewers : Set() from accumulate(
                            Viewing(
                                active==true,
                                $p : panelist),
                            collectSet($p))

$actualReach : Number( ) from accumulate (
    Panelist($weight : weight) from $viewers,
    sum($weight))
```

Comment: Remove this non-answer and edit your code with "additional info".

Comment: It isn't an answer since it raises a question. :-) I think I have explained why the original effort does not work.